# How To Filter A Subtotal in a Report

Tags: custom-reports

I have a report that returns the number of Work Orders per Contact. I created a Power of 1 formula field on the Work Order and it returns a subtotal. Is there a way to only see the number of Work Orders greater than 3, for example?

Comment: You are going to need a rollup field on Contact that has the count of WorkOrders to do this filter

Comment: would you show how did you realized that! Thanks?